# Fast C++ Graphics (as in programming time)

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, glut

I've played around with GLUT, but I've also read about SDL and one or two other graphics libraries. All I want to do at this point is 2D work. For what I'm doing right now, pixel by pixel plotting is all I need (say, plot(x,y,color) or something of the sort), but in the future I would appreciate the use of sprites. I've given point plotting a go with GLUT but it's rather non-intuitive coming from a B.A.S.I.C. background.

I work on both Ubuntu and Windows, so solutions for both systems are welcome.

Comment: Does it need to be in C++? It might be faster to learn something else in a different language. IMHO.

Comment: Depends. I've studied quite a few, though Java and C++ are my forte. 
What other language did you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

SDL is probably a good choice; another option to look at would be Qt (just subclass a QWidget and override its paintEvent() method and do your pixel plotting inside that).  Qt can also provide windowing/infrastructure support for OpenGL graphics if that's your preference.

Comment: A good SDL alternative/upgrade is SFML; I've heard people say it's faster than SDL and it's object oriented, as opposed to SDL which is made to be used in C as well as C++.

Comment: SFML, I'll check it out. Thanks. Qt too.